# Custom webform-mail template in Drupal 7 does not work

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

I'm trying to customise the webform email template for a specific webform following the steps in THEMING.txt, but those changes aren't being reflected in the form's default email template. I may have made a mistake in multiple places so I'm going to walk through my steps and hopefully someone will be able to spot what I did wrong :)

1) I copied the webform-mail.tpl.php template from /sites/all/modules/webform/templates directory over into the /themes/mytheme/ directory. Is that the correct place to drop it?

2) To test it, I simply changed some of the text. So I just changed 'Submitted on %date' to 'Entered on %date'.

3) I then renamed the page to webform-mail-1226.tpl.php, where 1226 is the number I see in the url when I go to edit the webform.

4) Then I tried to clear the cache, but I think this is the step I did wrong. The THEMING.txt file says to visit admin/settings/performance, but that path doesn't seem to work/exist for me. What I tried instead was admin/config/development/performance/ and then cleared the cache with the options here. Am I supposed to go somewhere else to clear a different cache?

5) I then went to the emails section corresponding to this form, and when I either go to an existing email or create a new one, the default email template does not reflect the changes I tried to implement.

Does anyone have any ideas why this isn't working? Thanks for your time and help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is checklist you need to verify:

1) Your Step 1 is okay nothing to worry.

2) If it is reflecting the change then it means default webform email template file is working fine.

3)* Here you need to verify node-id you used in filename. www.yoursite.com/node/xxx/webform, xxx = 1226 in the filename.

4) The Drupal 7 - Clear cache correct URL is admin/config/development/performance.

5)* Here you need to check in webform email setting you have to select "Default template".

Try selecting "Default template" the clear Drupal cache and then test.

Helpful [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/787874#comment-6321550).